# Why are these arrays getting passed by value and not by reference?

Tags: javascript, arrays, pass-by-reference

I was playing around with some design-patterns (*Module Reveal* and *Singleton* patterns) with basic stuff that worked as expected, like two utility functions that are shared with multiple objects, having one of them update the value of a String and the other copy a value of a String.

The unexpected thing happened when I turned the String to an Array, expecting it to get passed by reference, which it didn't for some reason:

**Test.js**

```
(function(win){
    var MainObj=(function(){
        var _alls = Object.create(null);

        function u_updateVal(){
            this.arr = ["up", "da", "ted"];
        }

        function u_copyVal(oName, prop){
            this[prop] = _alls[oName][prop];
        }

        function init(oName){
            if(typeof _alls[oName]==="undefined"){
                _alls[oName] = {
                    arr : ["def", "ault"],
                    updateVal : u_updateVal,
                    copyVal : u_copyVal
                };
            }

            return _alls[oName];
        }

        return {
            init : init
        };
    })();

    if(!win.MainObj){
        win.MainObj = MainObj;
    }
})(window);
```

**plain-js from the HTML**, depends on: Test.js

```
if(!window.MainObj){
    console.log("Error: MainObj is not defined");
}else{
    var a = MainObj.init("AA");
    var b = MainObj.init("BB");
    var c = MainObj.init("CC");

    b.updateVal();
    c.copyVal("BB", "arr");
    b.arr=["over", "written"];

    console.log(a.arr.join()); //def,ault
    console.log(b.arr.join()); //over,written
    console.log(c.arr.join()); //up,da,ted (I expected "over,written")
}
```

I expected `c.arr` to point at the same reference of `b.arr` since the copy from of the Array didn't had any precautions like splice/slice/JSONstringify/etc.

In an attempt to change things, I created another function to update the value via `b.otherUpdateVal();` instead of `b.arr = ["over", "written"];`, in hope it had something to do with a Closure thing beyond my current understanding of them, but this still gives the same result.

I can't seem to understand why these Arrays are not getting passed by reference (even though no special measures were taken to prevent this). Any thoughts why this might be happening?

**EDIT:** yep, this was just a silly oversight of thinking reassigning b would affect the already done reference of c. If you use `b.arr.push(".");` or sort, or anything that actually doesn't create a whole new Array, you do see both of them getting affected.

Comment: In what circumstances would you expect assigning a value to a property on one object to affect a property on a *different* object (ignoring obviously setter functions)?

Comment: Oops, my bad for not paying attention to what language that question was about. And StackOverflow's bad for saying it was the top related question. Should have been this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language?rq=1

Comment: @Pointy I actually don't, this was just a mistake from me

Comment: OK, well `b.arr = []` assigns a new value to the "arr" property of the object `b`.

Comment: that's why better to use functional programing :)

Comment: @Pointy do you think I should delete this question? It seems like it won't help anyone in the future, and it's not even a real duplicated. I voted to close as offtopic but I think this is just garbage that should totally be destroyed from earth leaving the least trace of its existence.

Comment: lol well it won't hurt my feelings either way :)

Comment: the system did't let me, anyway, it's a good reminder that sometimes small pebbles can sprain ankles too

Comment: @TheReason why, does the assignment operator work any different when you use FP in JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through what happens.

```
var a = MainObj.init("AA");
var b = MainObj.init("BB");
var c = MainObj.init("CC");
```

After this step you have.

```
a.arr; // ["def", "ault"]
b.arr; // ["def", "ault"]
c.arr; // ["def", "ault"]
```

Then we change `b`.

```
b.updateVal();
```

The rest stay the same, and b has updated.

```
b.arr; // ["up", "da", "ted"]
```

You then assign the same `b.arr` reference to `c.arr` in you `copyVal` function.

```
this[prop] = _alls[oName][prop]; // Copy the reference.
```

Your final change creates a whole **new** array and assigns it to `b`.

```
b.arr=["over", "written"];
```

And you get.

```
a.arr; // ["def", "ault"]
b.arr; // ["over", "written"] a new array you've created in the final step.
c.arr; // ["up", "da", "ted"] which is the old b array still being referenced.
```

Answer (score 1):

After this:

```
c.copyVal("BB", "arr");
```

the values of the "arr" properties of both `b` and `c` will be references to the same array. After this, however:

```
b.arr=["over", "written"];
```

you've overwritten the value of the "arr" property. That does not have any effect on the value of `c.arr`.

Comment: Note that as far as I can tell the confusion in the question has nothing to do with "passing" anything; it's just normal assignment operator behavior.

Comment: I don't know whats happening to me today lol, so silly mistake